# How can I use JFlex if i´m cloning a project from github

Tags: java, github, jflex

i'm currently working on a Lexer in Java, i'm using jflex to do this, when my partner runs the code it works, he pushed it into a repo in github. I cloned it and when trying to run it, it says it cannot find a symbol which is Lexer, this is a class that jflex creates. I

I was expecting to be able to use the jflex library, which is stored in the lib directory in the project, also, in the .vscode directory we created a settings.json in order to be able to use it, we thought it worked but apparently when someone clones the repo it doesn't work. How can i solve this?

Comment: Are you using a dependency management tool such as Maven or Gradle?

Comment: @BasilBourque i'm not, i'm kind of new to java so i actually don't know what maven or gradle is haha

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 1):

## Download needed library

Commonly, projects uploaded to GitHub omit the various [libraries](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Library_(computing)) needed by the app.

So you will need to manually obtain the needed library, usually a [JAR](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JAR_(file_format)) file. Then place that JAR file in a location accessible by your project.

When deploying your app, you will need to either include the library within your app, or make the library available on the runtime computer.

## Dependency management & build tool

Needed libraries are referred to as “dependencies”.

If doing any serious work in Java, I strongly recommend you learn how to use an [IDE](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integrated_development_environment) (such as [IntelliJ](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IntelliJ_IDEA), Eclipse, or NetBeans) in conjunction with a dependency management tool (such as [Apache Maven](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Apache_Maven) or Apache Gradle).

Tools like Maven & Gradle will automatically locate a copy of your declared dependency libraries, automatically download from a repository, and then install within your project.

These tools (IDEs, and dependency managers) do come with a learning curve. But that learning time is well spent if you are invested in being a Java developer.

Comment: Good advice for beginners!